# How to contributute an E4 MPartDescriptor to Eclipse via Fragments?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

How to contributute an E4 MPartDescriptor to Eclipse Plugins via Fragments?

I'm not talking about a standalone RCP application. The question concerns plugins that contribute Part Descriptors to an Eclipse IDE plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a model fragment to contribute a part descriptor
2. Select "Application" as container type and use `org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application` as "Extended Element ID" for your newly created model fragment.
3. Call your part descriptor as usual.

```java
MPart myPart = partService.createPart("MyPartDescriptorView");
partService.showPart(myPart, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

Comment: Are you sure `MyPartDescriptorView` is not the id you used for the view in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point? That how I read the source code.

Comment: I added it to org.eclipse.ui.views and registered it via fragment additionaly. You could be right. I'll check that.